# Python Crashcourse - 10-4 - Why won't my code version work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently learning python using Python Crashcourse. My question involves exercise 10-4 (Guest book). I'm trying to figure why my code won't work (I get a syntax error). My code is almost exactly the same as the book's.

My version:

```
with open(filename, 'a') as file_object:
            file_object.write(file_object"{name}\n")
        print(file_object"Hi {name}, you've been added to the guest book.")
```

The book's:

```
with open(filename, 'a') as f:
            f.write(f"{name}\n")
        print(f"Hi {name}, you've been added to the guest book.")
```

I know that all I have to do is shorten `file_object` to `f` and it will work, but my question is WHY doesn't `file_object` work? Isn't it just a variable like `f`? Why would length matter?

Comment: Please post your code with proper formatting (which is crucial with Python). Note that there is a code icon in the edit box. Use it. In any event -- what is `file_object"{name}\n"` even supposed to mean? There seems to be no reason to prepend a string by `file_object` -- what are you trying to accomplish by doing so?

Comment: If that is what the book does, it is simply awful. The `f` in `f.write` is different from the `f` in `f"{name}\n"`. The first `f` refers to a file but the second `f` is part of the syntax of what is called an `f-string`, which is one way to create formatted strings in Python. Using the same symbol to mean two very different things in a single line in a book which is aimed at beginners is very confusing. Given that context, your question is a good question.

Comment: Your comment seems unrelated to your question (which has been adequately answered below -- consider marking as accepted). If you have a further question, ask it as a different question.

Comment: I understand what you're saying now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a tutorial purpose this was a poor example on crashcourse.
the f for filename as a file handle is different then the f in the write/print line which is a format specifier.

```
with open(filename, 'a') as file_object:
    file_object.write(f"{name}\n")
    print(f"Hi {name}, you've been added to the guest book.")
```